# A question on relative compactness in two different spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

We are in the following situation: Suppose that $P$ is a projection on a Banach space $X$, and $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal L(X)$ is some set of bounded operators. Moreover, suppose that the set $\{T P : T \in \mathcal T\}$ is relatively compact in $\mathcal L(\operatorname{ran} P)$.

Can one show that $\mathcal A_x := \{T P x : T \in \mathcal T\}$ is relatively compact in $X$ for each $x \in X$?

I tried to show it as follows: Let $x \in X$ and $(T_n P x)_n$ a sequence in $\mathcal A_x$. By assumption the sequence $(T_n P)_n$ has a convergent subsequence, say $(T_{n_k} P)_k$. Thus, there is $S \in \mathcal L(\operatorname{ran} P)$ such that $T_{n_k} P \to S$ as $k \to \infty$. This implies that $T_{n_k} P y \to S y$ for each $y \in \operatorname{ran} P$. In particular, one has
$$T_{n_k} P x = T_{n_k} P P x \longrightarrow S P x,$$
which shows that $(T_{n_k} P x)_k$ converges. More precisely, we have shown that $(T_n P x)_n$ has a convergent subsequence. Thus, $\mathcal A_x$ is relatively compact.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.